# What's the difference between a normal navbar link, and one with the class = "navbar-link"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working my way through Microsoft's Intro to Bootstrap course (DEV203x) on edx. I came across this piece of info on there:

> To add normal links that are not to be considered as part of the navbar, add the navbar-link class to the a element. The anchor must be contained inside of a navbar-text container.

```
<div class="navbar-text">
  <a class="navbar-link" href="URL here">
    Follow us!
  </a>
</div>
```

Normal links are supposedly added like this:

```
<ul><li>
  <a href="URL here">
    A normal link!
  </a>
</li></ul>
```

There doesn't seem much difference in how these links appear on page. Only the styling for `navbar-text` is applied to `navbar-link` because it's enclosed in that tag.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be safe, normal links are added with `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`, not just a `ul` (which I'm pretty sure you know allready).

> For folks using standard links that are not within the regular navbar
>   navigation component, use the .navbar-link class to add the proper
>   colors for the default and inverse navbar options.

The differences may be subtle but they're important to know as they can be very useful. ***links that are not within*** the regular navigation is where this comes into play as you can use these classes to add text or links to your navbar that does not fall withing the standard `ul` + `li` structure.

In the examples you provide, there are differences (if even very small). There probably wouldn't be a need for this (**see Example 3**):

```
<div class="navbar-text">
  <a class="navbar-link" href="URL here">
    Follow us!
  </a>
</div>
```

as Bootstrap takes care of `HREFs` inside a `li` class as far as positioning and styling for it's navigation components so this wouldn't make sense and actually does break if you reduce your browser and open the collapsed navbar you'll see the link out of place in Example 3. You'll also see that if you hover over that first link, it will be underlined. This is not the case for a default navigation link.

As examples: If you need some text/link(s) to remain exposed when your navbar collapses for mobile, use these tags inside your `navbar-header` and they'll be positioned/styled appropriately so you won't (necessarily) have to write the CSS yourself. As well as inside the `navbar-collapse` panel but outside of the `ul` class.

See 3 examples in the following Snippet at Full Page.

1) Using these classes appropriately.

2) Same example structure as the **First** but without these classes applied.

3) What I believe your example illustrates.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3 class="alert alert-success">Example 1: Using Bootstrap classes</h3>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">This is navbar-text <a href="#" class="navbar-link">and this is a navbar-link</a>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-1">
      <p class="navbar-text">This is navbar-text <a href="#" class="navbar-link">and this is a navbar-link</a>

      </p>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<h3 class="alert alert-info">Example 2: Not using Bootstrap classes</h3>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-2" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <p class="not-navbar-text">This is NOT navbar-text <a href="#" class="not-navbar-link">and this is NOT navbar-link</a>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-2">
      <p class="not-navbar-text">This is NOT navbar-text <a href="#" class="not-navbar-link">and this is NOT navbar-link</a>

      </p>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<h3 class="alert alert-warning">Example 3: You example</h3>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-3" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <div class="navbar-text"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Follow us!</a>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Follow us!</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<h3 class="alert alert-success">Example 4: Navbar-Link</h3>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <p class="navbar-text"> <a href="#">Normal Link</a>  <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Navbar-link</a>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Normal Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Navbar-link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very nice explanation. Could you explain in which scenario is `navbar-link` more useful, ie where is this commonly used?

Comment: Navbar-link is only useful outside of the standard ul + li configuration as far a bootstrap navbar is concerned. It will apply the same coloration as you see in the links inside the ul + li instead of the default blue you'd see on any unstyled link in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is using the bootstrap structure for css/styling, while the second example is bare bones html. Bootstrap may not be applying anything in this case due to your own css/stylesheets overriding them, with out more information it is difficult to tell.

You will also want to confirm that you have bootstrap properly setup, as those should look different as per Bootstraps look. See here for an example of a navbar-link; http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-links.